# Best way to add items to collection

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have in column C, a listing of file names in numerical order (already sorted). I begin by looping through the folder where said files reside and adding it to a temp collection.

```
Do While file <> ""

l = Left(file, 3)
Length = Len(file)

If (l = "C") And Length = 13 Then
    tempCol.Add file
    Debug.Print file
Else
    GoTo none
End If

none:
'goto next file
file = Dir

Loop
```

Then I loop through the length of column C and compare each row (holding a filename) to the items in the temp collection. If filename is found in the temp collection, I add it to a separate collection (fCol).

```
For i = 17 To cccount
cc = wsSum.Cells(i, 3).value
For Each e In tempCol
If  "C" & cc = e  Then
fCol.Add e
Debug.Print e
End If
Next e
Next i
```

This is all fine except I feel like it could be done in just one loop/collection. I should be able to check if a filename in column C exists in the folder then add it to collection.

There's one slight curveball. The final collection has to be sorted. What's a good way to test the addition of items during the loop to sort it as it goes? Or should I do that in a separate step?

The filenames start with a "C" or "S" and I need to sort it by the number. So it should end like

S60100.XLSM
C60100.XLSM
S60270.XLSM
C60270.XLSM
C60275.XLSM
S60275.XLSM
S60280.XLSM
C60280.XLSM
S60285.XLSM
C60285.XLSM
S60290.XLSM
C60290.XLSM
C60295.XLSM
S60295.XLSM
C60300.XLSM
S60500.XLSM
C60500.XLSM
C60501.XLSM
C60503.XLSM

Edit: my fault. Should've mentioned that the filenames in column C only has the numbers! I know, huge thing to miss sorry :/

Edit 2: added picture of what sheet looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you post the full code - it's very difficult to see what's what without seeing how the variables are declared and assigned their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList` instead. An `ArrayList` object has a `.Contains()` method (should you need it) and a `.Sort()` method.

```
Sub MacroMan()

Dim arrayList As Object
Dim WS As Object
Dim tempFile As String
Const searchFolder As String = "C:\Users\MacroMan\Folder\" '// Note trailing '\'

Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each tempFile In Filter(Split(WS.Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & _
    searchFolder & "*.*"" /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

    If UCase(tempFile) Like "[CS][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][\.]XLSM" Then
        If Evaluate("=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & Mid(tempFile, 2, 5) & ",C:C,0)))") Then
            arrayList.Add tempFile
        End If
    End If
Next

arrayList.Sort

'// Print results -------
    For Each x In arrayList
        Debug.Print CStr(x)
    Next
'// ---------------------

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's some easy to understand examples of `ArrayList` and other collection objects: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167349

Comment: @findwindow it throws all files in the `seachFolder` into an array - much faster than using the `Dir()` method :)

Comment: regular expression - it's a pattern matching technique, again much faster. Here's an example of what it's doing: https://regex101.com/r/xL4cQ0/1

Comment: In short, this code runs a `DIR` command through a command prompt http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html and reads the output into an array, then it checks if each of the filenames is in the format C or S followed by 5 numbers and ".xlsm". If the name format is correct, and the filename exists in column C it adds it to the array list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx, the array list is then sorted and printed out.

Comment: I'm going to have to favourtie this and come back tomorrow to learn all these new useful things :)

Comment: lol SO TRUE zak. Btw, thank you. At least I got yours to work ^_^

Comment: You may have to change it to `"[CS][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\.]XLSM"` I can't remember if VBA RegEx allows for limits (as in `{5}`) - my bad.

Comment: It's supposed to be `NOT(ISERROR())` - You only want to to add if it finds the filename in the list in column C right?

Comment: tempFile will be the name of the file in the searchFolder - that If statement is checking to see if conforms to the pattern C or S, followed by 5 numbers and ".xlsm" - the next If statement (inner) checks if that filename exists in column C, if it does it adds it to the array list. If column C has files to be **excluded** then remove the `=NOT(` as you suggested.

Comment: aaaahhh - Is the column C you want in another sheet? Not the active sheet?

Comment: oh :( - the `Evaluate()` method will accept a string that represents a formula (see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx ), in a formula you would use "C:C" to refer to column C in the active sheet. As it's the active sheet it doesn't need to be qualified with a sheet name/object

Comment: Can't say without seeing your sheet - can you make a mock-up and post me a link? in dropbox or something? Or find my site in my profile and email me a copy

Comment: grrr. Apparently VBA doesn't like `[\d]` change the pattern to `"[SC][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][\.]XLSM"` see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx - I've edited my answer to show the pattern

Comment: again, really hard to tell without seeing your data :( first 3 letters you could do `If UCase(Left(tempFile, 3)) = "DIV" Then`

Comment: 1) What do you mean they _appear_ as numbers? is it a hyperlink? or a formula? 2) Change `[SC]` to `DIV` (no square brackets)

Comment: formula like =book.sheet.range

Comment: YAY IT WORKED ^_____^ THANK YOU <3 One slight problem. I added an or to the outer if statement to test for S and it's throwing a type mismatch error for a filename that has already been added. But it's only the C that has been added. The S should add too??

Comment: Show me what you've changed the If statement to

Comment: arraylist is a game changer with built in sort!!! Thank you so much for all your help ^_^

Comment: Happy to help :) - The `Contains()` method is very useful too - no need to loop to check values.

Comment: Doh. Spoke too soon. It sorts by first character. I needed by number XD Hmm I just need to adjust tempfile.

Comment: Cool. I can add mid(tempfile) which sorts all numbers together. I can prefix letter in another loop. Edit or use contains() simul to prefix. WIN

Answer (score 2):

Use an array instead. Then you can easily sort it afterwards. Plus, arrays are much MUCH faster than continuously referencing worksheet ranges.

Key aspects of this approach:

[1] Define your column range, create an array of that size, put the data range into an array.

[2] A nested loop then takes care of the rest. For each filename, loop through your arrayColumnList (could also use vlookup) until it finds a match, or doesn't. MAtches go in the final array.

```
Sub ArrayList()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Dim arrList As Variant
    arrList = Array()

Dim lngFinalRow As Long
Dim lngColumnNumber As Long
'/ Used to define the range of your column data

Dim strLeftCharacter As String
Dim lngFileLength As Long

Dim lngFilesFound As Long

Dim arrColumnData As Variant
    arrColumnData = Array()

Dim rngColumnData As Range
    '/ set rngColumnData = Range( etc.)
    ReDim arrColumnData(1 To rngColumnData.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    arrColumnData = rngColumnData

'/ At this point you need to convert your numbers to strings with the filename Character. Like this:

'/ for i = Lbound(array,1) to ubound(array,1)
'/ array(i, 1) = "C" & Cstr(array(i,1))
'/ next i

Dim bMatchFound As Boolean

    '/ define dir filepath
    lngFilesFound = 0
    Do Until file = ""

        strLeftCharacter = Left(file, 1) '/ Don't know why you were using 3 when you're only checking for the first character?
        lngFileLength = Len(file)

        If strLeftCharacter = "C" And lngFileLength = 13 _
            Then
                bMatchFound = False
                i = LBound(arrColumnData, 1)
                Do While bMatchFound = False And i <= UBound(arrColumnData, 1)
                    If arrColumnData(i, 1) = file Then bMatchFound = True
                    i = i + 1
                Loop

                If bMatchFound = True _
                    Then
                        lngFilesFound = lngFilesFound + 1
                        ReDim preserve arrList(1 To lngFilesFound)
                        arrList(lngFilesFound) = file
                        Debug.Print file
                End If
        End If

        file = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

That will give you a one-dimensional (I.E. list) array with your filenames. You can find simple array-sorting subs with a google search.

Comment: Oh, whoops :) I forgot that range arrays do still have a 2nddimension, it's just 1-1. It should be arrColumnData(i, 1)

Comment: Okay. DO you know how to use the locals window?

Comment: I want you to step through your code using F8 and watch the locals window, and check that everything is what it's supposed to be (E.G. the ColumnData array actually contains the column data, the file is actually a string with a filename etc.)

Comment: Hmm I see you added C but what about S? Do I need new array?

Comment: Up to you really. You could write a separate macro with S instead of C. You could go through the list, remove C from each element and add S. All depends on what you're comfortable programming.

Comment: Oh. need to add ext XD

Answer (score 1):

You will not need the second collection if you use this modification of your initial code:

```
Sub UsingOnlyOneCollection()

    Do While file <> ""

        l = Left(file, 3)
        Length = Len(file)

        If (l = "C") And Length = 13 Then
            If Evaluate("IFERROR(MATCH(""" & file & """,C:C,),)") Then  '<--- I added this
                tempCol.Add file
                Debug.Print file
            End If
        Else
            GoTo none
        End If

none:
        'goto next file
        file = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @findwindow It works here. Perhaps your data is not in the sheet as I imagined. Could you send me a small sample workbook? I'm sure I can get this solution working with the actual data, and get it back to you quickly. My email is daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: @findwindow Can't be certain without seeing it. Please send me the file if you can.

Comment: OK. On a new sheet try placing a couple of full filename values in column C. For example in C1 put this: `S60100.XLSM` and in C2 put this: `C60270.XLSM`, etc. Now step through the code and override the `file` value with one of the full filenames use entered into column C. You'll see that it works...

Comment: The easiest way is to build the formula on the worksheet, just like you would do for any formula on a worksheet. Once it works, then copy to clipboard and to to VBE and paste it... you then have to replace any hard-coded values with variables. For example, on the worksheet enter this formula: `=IFERROR(MATCH("C60100.XLSM",C:C,),)` If that full file name exists in column C you'll get the row number as the result. If it does not exist, you'll get ZERO.

Comment: Good idea. Macroman has you beat though. His is even more sophisticated =P Edit: he did steal your evaluate though ^_^;

Comment: @findwindow Yeah. I was not trying to re-write your entire method. I focused in exactly on your question of how to use your code with just one collection... not needing that whole other bit.

Comment: This is a very elegant answer but no sort.